# Javascript change html div color based on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have some AJAX that populates a variable with the results of a PHP script every 3 seconds in order to update a gauge widget I am using to display energy data in near real time.

What I would like to do, is change either the border or background color of the DIV that this gauge exists in, based on the current value stored in the variable.

Here is my code: (Many thanks to the few on here that helped me with this, I can't take credit for it)...

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url:'/newparser.php'
    }).done(function(response) {
        resultvalue=response;
        $("#gauge").wijradialgauge({value:resultvalue});
    });
},3000);
```

Now I have a DIV in the body called `officekw` which has a border-color property set in its tag.

Can an IF statement exist in this AJAX code that checks the value of `resultvalue` and if it is above 4 for example, change the `officekw` DIV border or background color to say yellow?

The value of `resultvalue` is only ever a number formatted to 1dp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url:'/newparser.php'
    }).done(function(response) {
        resultvalue=response;

        $('#officekw').css('border-color', function(){
            if (parseFloat(resultvalue) > 4) {
                return 'yellow';
            }
            else {
                return '#000';
            }
        });

        $("#gauge").wijradialgauge({value:resultvalue});
    });
},3000);
```

[Simple illustrative demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qV8At/2/).

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly! Another quick question, is there a way to insert another condition into that IF that turns the border red if the value is greater that 8 as well?

Comment: Of course, simply amend the `if` and supply an `else if` condition: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qV8At/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can as following

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/newparser.php'
    }).done(function (response) {
        resultvalue = response;
        if (resultvalue > 4) {
            $("#officekw").attr("border-color", "yellow");
        }
        $("#gauge").wijradialgauge({
            value: resultvalue
        });
    });
}, 3000);
```